# How to export and import the databases in MySql.

Tags: mysql, xampp

phpMyAdmin shows an error during importing the exported .sql file. It gives message like this
SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `mcadatabase`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `trick`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trick` (
`id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(20000) NOT NULL,
  `option1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `option2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `option3` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `option4Right` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1046 - No database selected

Answer (score 3):

With phpMyAdmin, you need to create a database named `mcadatabase`. Then, select this database and select `Import`.

Comment: The easiest method for exporting a database is this. Commandline methods did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use command Line to import/export database

Import:

- C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysql -u username -p databasename < file_name.sql

Export:

- C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysqldump -u username -p databasename > file_name.sql

Answer (score 1):

For Exporting  open a terminal :-

```
mysql -u root -p your_database_name > any_file_name.sql
```

For Importing:-

```
mysql -u root -p < sql_file_name.sql
```

For exporting only a table in your database:-

```
 mysql -u root -p your_database_name your_table_name > any_file_name.sql
```

Importing a table remains same as above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at mysqldump (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > /path/to/file/dump.sql
```

Comment: Please add further explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Export

```
mysqldump -u username –-password=your_password database_name > file.sql
```

Import

```
mysql -u username –-password=your_password database_name < file.sql
```